# Task View causes "sticky" Win key

Tags: windows, touchpad, task-view

For some reason whenever I pull up Task View using a touchpad gesture (4 finger swipe down - I have a Samsung laptop with Elantech software), it causes the Win key to become sticky (i.e. simply typing 'R' on my keyboard will open up the Run dialog). It resolves when I restart or lock the computer. No similar issue when I press the Task View button from the actual taskbar.

I recently updated to Windows 10, and reinstalled my touchpad drivers, but this problem has existed since I got the laptop.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 uses a generic trackpad for the Elan touchpad. To correct this follow these steps:

1. Download the latest Elantech driver: http://www.station-drivers.com/index.php?option=com_remository&Itemid=353&func=download&id=1675&chk=d3edc55ebf64cf59602143405e88c3de&no_html=1
2. Go to Device Manager and look for the touchpad
3. Right Click Update Driver Software > **Browse My computer ...** > **Let me pick from a list**
4. Unselect **Show Incompatible Hardware**
5. Find **ELAN** or **ETD** and select the appropriate driver
6. To ensure changes to the driver do not occur without your knowledge, open the Control Panel (right-click Start button and select Control Panel)
7. Navigate to System and Security > System > Advanced system settings
8. Click Hardware tab > Device Installation Settings and select **No, let me choose what to do option**
9. Select **Never install driver software from Windows Update**